# Finger selection UI screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am creating layout for finger selection. In this I am trying to achieve click events for each individual finger. This layout should be uniform on any type of screen resolution.

**My approach:**

Inside relative layout, I am assigning radio buttons (not radio group but individual) to each finger inside hand image using margins and padding but it is not resting properly over finger image. They are slightly moving left or right.

**Problem in this** - radio button positions is changing if screen resolution changes.

[image]

I failed to find library for such click events. Also in SO I didn't find any related questions. Can someone guide me in this to library or example or better approach than this?

Answer (score 0):

A several years ago I worked on the similar task. Unfortunately, I don't remember the whole solution, but idea was pretty simple. In my case it was an image of the map where a user could select a district by tapping the map. I knew the resolution of the original image that I used to display in UI. I encoded each district against its boundaries so it gave me a list of pair's number. I had a touch listener attached to ImageView that was used to display the map. So every time a user clicked on the map I got a position of his click, multiply this value by a scale factor(this one was calculated based on the size of original image and the one that was scaled by Android). Then I checked if that value laid in any polygons.

So to make it more clear:

1. Let width, height = size of original image
2. x, y = user touch
3. scaleWidth, scaleHeight = size of the image displayed by Android on the user device
4. scaleX = scaleWidth / width, scaleY = scaleHeight / height
5. originalX = scaleX * x, originalY = scaleY * y
6. Then check if originalX and originalY fits in polygons. In your case those polygons could be just squares around every finger.